# "Invalid Initializer Member Declarator"

Tags: c#, list

I found [a video](https://youtu.be/ih20l3pJoeU) about making a simple 3D graphics engine (in c++) and I have been trying to port it to c# (I'm not very experienced in either language). I have been running into an issue while defining the triangles of a cube.

Here is the troublesome code:

```
private mesh meshCube = new mesh();

meshCube.tris = new List<triangle>{
                new triangle {p = new vec3d[] { 
                    new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f, z = 0.0f },
                    new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
                    new vec3d { x = 1.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
                },
                //From this point onward the error message "Invalid initializer member declarator" is displayed.
                new triangle {p = new vec3d[] { 
                    new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f, z = 0.0f },
                    new vec3d { x = 1.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
                    new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
                },
            };
```

I'm not quite sure what the error message actually means, or how to solve it.

Here are the data types referenced in the code if it is helpful:

```
struct vec3d
{
    public float x, y, z;
}
struct triangle
{
    public vec3d[] p;
}

struct mesh 
{
    public List<triangle> tris;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new List<triangle>{
     new triangle {p = new vec3d[] {
         new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f, z = 0.0f },
         new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
         new vec3d { x = 1.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
     }, <---
     new triangle {p = new vec3d[] {
         new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f, z = 0.0f },
         new vec3d { x = 1.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
         new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
     },
 };
```

The closing bracket marked with "`<---`" above closes off the `new vec3d[] {`. But the `vec3d[]` is in a `new triangle {` , which hasn't been closed off yet! So inside the first triangle's object initialiser, you try to start a second `new triangle`, which is not allowed. The compiler expects a `property = value` there.

Indented properly, this is how your code looks:

```
new List<triangle>{
     new triangle {
        p = new vec3d[] {
            new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f, z = 0.0f },
            new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
            new vec3d { x = 1.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
        },
        
        new triangle { ... } // this is inside the first triangle!
     },
 };
```

You need to close off each triangle, as well as each vec3d:

```
new List<triangle>{
     new triangle {p = new vec3d[] {
         new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f, z = 0.0f },
         new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
         new vec3d { x = 1.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
     }},
     new triangle {p = new vec3d[] {
         new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f, z = 0.0f },
         new vec3d { x = 1.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
         new vec3d { x = 0.0f, y = 1.0f, z = 0.0f },
     }},
 };
```